# Capture Client Time of Click on Image in Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'd like to know when a user clicks on an image in a Shiny app. My full app displays images in a kind of "Photo Hunt" game and I want to capture how long it takes the user to click on a relevant place in each image. However, I'm having a hard time capturing client-side time, which is important because server-side times can be delayed for various reasons. I think I would need something like the following javascript, but I do not know how to integrate it in the app.

1. Find the element on the page

```
var image = document.getElementById('img');
```

2. Listen for the click and capture the time

```
addEventListener("click", true,
click_time = new Date().getTime();)
```

3. Send the captured time to shiny server with something like:

```
Shiny.onInputChange("new_click_time",click_time);
```

4. Listen in shiny to get the click_time

```
observeEvent(input$new_click_time,{
  # This should be the time the user clicked on the image:
   input$new_click_time
})
```

Here's an example shiny app that gets server-time, but not client-time:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
options(digits.secs = 3)     # Modify default global time to show milleseconds

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        p("When clicking on the histogram, I'd like to capture the client-side computer's time"),
        actionButton(inputId="new_image", label= "New Image")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        imageOutput("img", click = "photo_click"),
        textOutput("client_time"),
        textOutput("server_time")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {


    output$img <- renderImage({
      input$new_image

      outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
      png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
      hist(rnorm(100))
      dev.off()

      list(src = outfile,
           alt = "This is alternate text")
    },
    deleteFile = TRUE)

    output$server_time <- renderText({
      req(input$photo_click)

      server.time <- as.character(strptime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))    # Time with milliseconds
      paste("SERVER TIME:", server.time)
    })

    output$client_time <- renderText({
      # cat("\nI'd like to capture click-time, possibly here -- the time on the client's machine when a click is made")
      req(input$photo_click)
      client.time <- "???"    # Time with milliseconds
      paste("CLIENT TIME:", client.time)
    })


  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the javascript function `Shiny.setInputValue` supplied by Shiny to the client. Example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
                 img(id = 'trigger_image', 
                     src = 'notfound.jpg',
                     height = '100px',
                     width = '100px'
                     ),
                 tags$script('
              document.getElementById("trigger_image").onclick = function(){
              var the_time = new Date().getTime();
              // set input$client_time to the_time:
              Shiny.setInputValue("client_time", the_time)}
        ')
        )

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$client_time,{
        ## do stuff with input$client_time
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that Javascript `getTime` returns milliseconds elapsed since 1970/1/1.

Shiny: [Communicating with Javascript](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)

**Edit**

If you have to measure the time elapsed between updating the image at the client and the user responding (clicking on the fresh image), you can capture and calculate the duration between both events at the client side like this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    tags$script('
    // ------ javascript code ------
    // $(document).ready(...) ensures execution only after document is fully rendered
    // so that events like .onclick can be attached 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // function to set Shiny input value to current time: 
        const clockEvent = function(inputName){Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, new Date().getTime())}
        // trigger when the value of output id "trigger_image" changes: 
        $(document).on("shiny:value",
               function(event){
                   if (event.target.id === "trigger_image") {clockEvent("displayed_at")}
               }
              )
        // trigger when the image, after being sent or refreshed, is clicked:
        document.getElementById("trigger_image")
                    .onclick = function(){clockEvent("reacted_at")}
    })
    // ------------------------------
    '),
    shiny::imageOutput('trigger_image'),
    actionButton('show_new', 'show new image'),
    textOutput('reaction_time')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show_new,{
        output$trigger_image <- shiny::renderImage(list(id = 'trigger_image',
                                                        'src' = 'image001.png'
                               ), deleteFile = FALSE)
                               
        output$reaction_time <- renderPrint(paste('reaction time (ms)', input$reacted_at - input$displayed_at))
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. One issue: I need the image to be dynamically created within the server, such as in my example. I'm trying to revise your example to work, but am not having luck.

Comment: Hi I_0, I took what you did and almost made it work dynamically -- see my answer below. However, I can't seem to get the client side `get.Time()` to trigger before the server side `Sys.time()`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: dca, just to make sure: you want to know how long it takes the user from seeing the fresh image until reacting to it, don't you? If so, both events should be timed at the client side, but I couldn't yet work out how to capture the event of a single DOM element (=image) being rendered (`window.onload` did not work).

Comment: @i-o, yes, that's the goal! Agreed that it should be timed at the client side, I just can't get it to work.

Comment: please see edit to initial answer; hope it works!

Comment: I think that works! I revised it to fit my case and noticed that the `tags$script` with the JS needs to be beneath the image_container div. If I place the JS in the head or "earlier" in the UI, there is an error re: onclick not found. I wonder if there is a more robust way to write that function so that it finds the container whenever it is rendered. Either way, thanks.

Comment: Javascript code inside `$(document).ready(...)` will be executed only after the document is fully loaded, so all DOM elements (like the image_container `<DIV>`) will be there to attach mouse events to. Please see latest edit, and thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @I-O, When I tried to integrate this with more of my app, it failed. Can you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654533/attach-javascript-listener-when-using-renderui-in-shiny-app

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to capture the client's time, but I don't see how it can be correct, because the client's time is AFTER the server's time.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
options(digits.secs = 3)     # Modify and save default global time options


click.time.image.js <- "

  document.getElementById('img').onclick = function(){
      var the_time = new Date().getTime();
      console.log(the_time);
      // set input$client_time to the_time:
      Shiny.setInputValue('client_time', the_time)
}
        "

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        p("When clicking on the histogram, I'd like to capture the client-side computer's time"),
        actionButton(inputId="new_image", label= "New Image")
        ),
      mainPanel(
        imageOutput("img", click = "photo_click"),
        textOutput("client_time"),
        textOutput("server_time")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$img <- renderImage({
      input$new_image

      outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
      png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
      hist(rnorm(100))
      dev.off()

      shinyjs::runjs(click.time.image.js)

      list(src = outfile,
           alt = "This is alternate text")
    },
    deleteFile = TRUE)



    output$server_time <- renderText({
      req(input$photo_click)
      server.time <- as.character(strptime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))    # Time with milliseconds
      paste("SERVER TIME:", server.time)
    })

    output$client_time <- renderText({
      req(input$photo_click)
      req(input$client_time)
      client.time <- input$client_time    # Time with milliseconds
      client.time <- as.POSIXct(client.time/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
      paste("CLIENTs TIME:", client.time)
    })


  }
)
```