# Attach javascript listener when using `renderUI` in Shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am ultimately trying to capture the time it takes a user to click on a series of histograms after they are displayed. However, in the example app below, a javascript error appears at the loading of the app:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
> at HTMLDocument. ((index):31:30)
> at e (jquery.min.js:2:30038)
> at t (jquery.min.js:2:30340)

Presumably this is because `document.getElementById("img")` doesn't find `img` at the loading of the app, but I don't know how to resolve that.

I can get this to work when the histogram is displayed outside of the `renderUI`, but I need to change the histogram dynamically from the server, so I need this to work with a rendered UI.

```
shinyApp(
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script('
    // ------ javascript code ------
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // function to set Shiny input value to current time: 
        const clockEvent = function(inputName){Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, new Date().getTime())}
        // trigger when the value of output id "img" changes: 
        $(document).on("shiny:value",
               function(event){
                   if (event.target.id === "img") {clockEvent("displayed_at")}
               }
              )
        // trigger when the image, after being sent or refreshed, is clicked:
        document.getElementById("img")
                    .onclick = function(){clockEvent("reacted_at")}
    })
    // ------------------------------
    '),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

        actionButton(inputId="render_dynamic", label= "Create Dynamic UI")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        uiOutput("dynamic")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$img <- renderImage({
      outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
      png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
      hist(rnorm(100))
      dev.off()
      
      list(src = outfile,
           contentType = "image/jpeg")
    },
    deleteFile = FALSE)

    output$reaction_time <- renderPrint(paste('reaction time (ms)', input$reacted_at - input$displayed_at))
    
    output$dynamic <- renderUI({
      
      req(input$render_dynamic > 0)
      
      div(id = 'image_container',
          imageOutput("img", click = "photo_click"),
          textOutput("reaction_time"))
      
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: There is no need to use `renderUI`. `renderImage` is also reactive, so you can change the histogram from the server without `renderUI`. Is there any reason why you don't use `renderPlot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach avoiding `renderUI` and using `bindEvent`:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  tags$script('
    // ------ javascript code ------
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // function to set Shiny input value to current time: 
        const clockEvent = function(inputName){Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, new Date().getTime())}
        // trigger when the value of output id "img" changes: 
        $(document).on("shiny:value",
               function(event){
                   if (event.target.id === "img") {clockEvent("displayed_at")}
               }
              )
        // trigger when the image, after being sent or refreshed, is clicked:
        document.getElementById("img")
                    .onclick = function(){clockEvent("reacted_at")}
    })
    // ------------------------------
    '),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId="render_dynamic", label= "Create Dynamic UI")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("img"),
      textOutput("reaction_time")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$img <- renderImage({
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
    png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
    hist(rnorm(100))
    dev.off()
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType = "image/jpeg")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE) |> bindEvent(input$render_dynamic)
  
  output$reaction_time <- renderPrint({
      paste('reaction time (ms)', input$reacted_at - input$displayed_at)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$reacted_at)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't know if there is a good reason for you to output the plot as an image and show it via `renderImage` instead of using `renderPlot` directly - but here is the `renderPlot` version:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  tags$script('
    // ------ javascript code ------
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // function to set Shiny input value to current time: 
        const clockEvent = function(inputName){Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, new Date().getTime())}
        // trigger when the value of output id "img" changes: 
        $(document).on("shiny:value",
               function(event){
                   if (event.target.id === "img") {clockEvent("displayed_at")}
               }
              )
        // trigger when the image, after being sent or refreshed, is clicked:
        document.getElementById("img")
                    .onclick = function(){clockEvent("reacted_at")}
    })
    // ------------------------------
    '),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId="render_dynamic", label= "Create Dynamic UI")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("img"),
      textOutput("reaction_time")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$img <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(100))
  }) |> bindEvent(input$render_dynamic)
  
  output$reaction_time <- renderPrint({
      paste('reaction time (ms)', input$reacted_at - input$displayed_at)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$reacted_at)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: If you are still interested in how to solve the `renderUI` problem please check the following [post on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3348#issuecomment-810727477).

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to use RenderUI because I render various various pages that a user progresses through. But perhaps I can use this and re-write the code to use conditionalPanel or perhaps just rendering the various UI components conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like, from the client's perspective, the document is fully loaded before you `renderUI` another element. So the JQuery `$(document).ready(...)` gives its OK to proceed with trying to attach an event to an element which is not there (yet).

Options to avoid `renderUI` have already been given. If you don't want the "placeholder" blank space, you can set the image height to zero upon rendering:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
## ...
    imageOutput("img", click = "photo_click",
    height = 0
    )
## ...
```